# combine multiple feeds with fetch_feed and display blog titles for each item?

Tags: feed, simplepie

I'm trying to display multiple feeds using the fetch_feed function. Its working well thus far except I can't figure out why the title for each individual rss feed will not show up.
Here is my code:

```
<?php // Get RSS Feed(s)
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
$rsslist = array(   'http://www.lt11.com/rss',
                    'http://feeds.feedburner.com/climbingnarc'
                );
$rss = fetch_feed($rsslist);
if (!is_wp_error( $rss ) ) : 
$maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(25); 
$rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems); 
endif;
?>
    <?php if ($maxitems == 0) echo '<li>No items.</li>';
    else
    foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>
    <li class="feed"> 
        <a href='<?php echo esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ); ?>'
        title='<?php echo 'Posted '.$item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a'); ?>'>
        <?php echo esc_html( $item->get_date('j/n/Y - g:i A') ); ?> - <div class="feeditemtitle"><?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?></div> - <?php echo esc_html($rss->get_title() ); ?></a>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Its that list bit that calls for the title of the rss feed. If I only fetch one feed then the title shows up. When I fetch more than one feed as in the example above, the title does not show up. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything to suggest that [`fetch_feed`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed) is supposed to accept an array of values. That is not mentioned in the Codex, nor the source, [`@param string $url URL to retrieve feed`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/feed.php#L523).

That said, `fetch_feed` passes things off to SimplePie's [`set_feed_url($url);`](http://simplepie.org/wiki/reference/simplepie_item/get_feed) which does accept an array. And that Simplepie docs page is, I think, where your answer is. The RSS feed name is `$item->get_feed()->get_title()` not `$rss->get_title()`

I am still a bit cautious since you are passing an array through a WordPress function that doesn't appear to be meant for it.

Comment: Passing an array in is fine; the WordPress function is just incorrectly documented, see WP bug [#22140](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22140).

Comment: Thanks @RyanMcCue. Looks like there is a patch for the source documentation. Maybe I'll straighten out the Codex.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Thank you so much! That worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score 0):

Display above code with featured image ...

```
<div class="clearfix">
<?php 

include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
$rsslist = array(   'http://www.bloggingwizard.com/feed',
                    'http://www.wpbeginner.com/feed/'
                );
$rss = fetch_feed($rsslist);
if (!is_wp_error( $rss ) ) : 
$maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(5); 
$rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems); 
endif;
?>
<?php function get_first_image_url($html)
        {
            if (preg_match('/<img.+?src="(.+?)"/', $html, $matches)) {
            return $matches[1];
            }
        }
?>  


    <?php if ($maxitems == 0) echo '<li>No items.</li>';
    else
    foreach ( $rss_items as $item ) : ?>
    <div class="col-md-4"> 

    <div class="rss-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo get_first_image_url($item->get_content()) ?>');height: 200px;
    background-size: cover;">

        </div>

        <a href='<?php echo esc_url( $item->get_permalink() ); ?>'
        title='<?php echo 'Posted '.$item->get_date('j F Y | g:i a'); ?>'>
       <div class="feeditemtitle">
       <?php echo esc_html( $item->get_title() ); ?></div>  <?php echo esc_html($rss->get_title() ); ?></a>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>   

</div>
```